# how i can avoid my data lost when i updates my apps in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When using PhoneGap, do users lose all of their saved data when they update an iOS app downloaded from iTunes?

I am hoping that anything stored in either Webstorage  feature in Construct 2 will be preserved whenever someone downloads a new version of the app from iTunes, but I'm afraid to build a whole Apps only to have a bunch of upset users when they update the app. I know when I build an app in Objective C I have to go through some hoops to get the Core Data store to migrate correctly.

The other option is to mirror the data to an external server/database, but I want to avoid that expense and complication if I can.

Comment: can i save my default data i my database before run any application? have any facility in core data to add my default data in the database??

Comment: Is your data store Core Data?

Comment: yes i am using core data

Comment: what can i do ? u have any suggestion

Comment: have any other database option to store my database ?

Comment: Okay well the question is, have you changed anything in your database (Core Data) i.e keys of entities, added entities etc?

Comment: If you haven't changed anything then you don't need to worry. If you have then have a look at this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-core_data_modeling_tool/Articles/creating_new_version.html

Comment: no   i want only add my default data in my database before i run my apps

Answer (score 0):

If you change anything in the tables in CoreData then you would have to implement migration for the tables by creating a new version (check apple's documentation here: [Lightweight Migration](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html))

Otherwise if you don't change anything updating the app would not make the user lose any data.